# What is the physical reason of the mirror principle in the stellar evolution?

Tags: star, stellar-evolution, star-formation

I understand that stars transition into the red giant phase by obeying the mirror principle, as written [here](http://low-sky.github.io/stellarev/):

> Shell-burning stars obey something called the mirror principle, which is an observation gleaned from the models that when a shell contracts, the envelope of the star will expand and vice versa.

However, I read that this information was gleaned from observation. Could anyone explain the reason or the physics behind why this happens?

Comment: What is the "mirror principle"? I googled for it and did not find anything.

Comment: I found it here: http://low-sky.github.io/stellarev/

Comment: "Shell-burning stars obey something called the mirror principle, which is an observation gleaned from the models that when a shell contracts, the envelope of the star will expand and vice versa."

Comment: Thanks! I understood the post and clarified it.

Comment: Section 12.4 of https://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~pettini/STARS/Lecture12.pdf addresses this, although a proper answer would need more of a dive into the physics, especially the virial theorem, which I have never understood properly.